# Sending parameters with the autogenerated post submit/create button in MVC 3 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I read online about how to send a variable from javascript with ajax but I am not sure that solution fit my needs.
What I am trying to do is this:
I have an automated form for creating a row at my DB.
What I Want to do is run a javascript code that will create a variable with logic based on the user input and than send this variable along with all the other fields that are automatically being sent because of the automated creation and binding of the model.
Basically what I want is to add another array to the automated post call that I didn't wrote because it is being generated automatically by mvc. and than I can retrieve this variable (array at my case) at the create method on the controller

Do you have a solution for this?
Thank you very much

Comment: if I understood well, are you talking about initializing some variables at the page load?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some hidden fields to the form and use Javascript to fill their values in the submit event.